# Use of switch and case in php and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, switch-statement, case

I want use of `switch` and `case` in php and codeigniter library, i try it as following code, But I not receive output. what do i do?

**Demo:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wq0Noj

```
function indicators() {
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $Year = '1355';
    $Month = '03';

    switch ($Year) {
        case 1354:
            $key=array('0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6');
            $output = $key[$Month-1];
            break;
        case 1355:
            $key=array('0.6','0.7','0.2','0.4','0.7','0.1','0.7','0.2','0.5','0.9','0.4','0.8');
            $output = $key[$Month-1];
            break;
        echo $output; // The output should be: 0.7
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `echo` out of the `switch`-block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `echo` needs to be outside of the `switch` as well... checking to verify.

Yep, the echo needs to be outside. The type should actually be coerced when comparing.

```
<?php

$s = '5';

switch ($s) {
    case 5:
        echo "Foo\n";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Bar\n";
        break;
}

echo $s;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Foo
5
```

And for your example:

```
<?php

function indicators() {
    $Year = '1355';
    $Month = '03';

    switch ($Year) {
        case 1354:
            $key=array('0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6','0.6');
            $output = $key[$Month-1];
            break;
        case 1355:
            $key=array('0.6','0.7','0.2','0.4','0.7','0.1','0.7','0.2','0.5','0.9','0.4','0.8');
            $output = $key[$Month-1];
            break;
    }
    echo $output; // The output should be: 0.7
}

indicators();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0.2
```

Which is correct according to the code.  `'03' - 1 == 2`.  `$key[2] == '0.2'`

As pointed out in the comment below by @vstm, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) state that the "switch/case does loose comparision."

Comment: Yep, `switch` does "loose comparison" as documented in the... [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).